# componentDidMount not getting called

Tags: jsx, babeljs, wordpress-gutenberg

Simple component used in a Gutenberg block both in edit: and save: In this simplified example it simply sets a state variable in componentDidMount then has render() pick it up and show it. This works as expected in the back end but when I try and view the page render() can't see the variable, it's not there. Nailing the problem is being made harder because console.logs aren't showing in the console in the front end. I don't know if this is a part of the same problem or not. Thoughts appreciated.

```
( function( blocks, element ) {

    blocks.registerBlockType( 'daisy/grid-view', {
        title: 'Daisy: Single Image View',
        icon: 'universal-access-alt',
        category: 'common',

        attributes: {
            pid         : {type: 'number'},
        },

        edit: function( props ) {

        return( 
        <p>
            <DaTest></DaTest>
        </p>)

        },
        save: function( props ) {

            console.log( "save")
            return (

                <p>xxx
                    <DaTest></DaTest>
                </p>
            )
        },
    } );
}(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.editor

) );
```

--

```
class DaTest extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log( "in test")

        var xxx = JSON.stringify( this.state )
        return  (
            <div>
                inside DaTest Render [{xxx }] // xxx shows as {}
            </div>
        )
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState( {aaa : "aaa" })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like I've misunderstood the way blocks work in Gutenberg. It's the rendered output that's being passed in save, the front end never sees the component.

Rethink.